# SearchController Hidden automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I try to show searchController in UIViewcontroller.
This works fine but when I try to write something then search controller is not visible.

My code is as follow:

```
class tempVC: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter name here..."
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation=false
        //navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 44)
        self.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    }


    // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        // let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        //let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        //filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
        print("update")
    }

}
```

**Please help me to solve this.**

**Thank you,**

Answer (score -1):

class tempVC: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter name here..."
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation=false
    //navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 44)
    self.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
}


// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    // let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    //let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
    //filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
    print("update")
}
```

}

Comment: what is the change in your answer?